# access Microsoft Graph without user - missing 'grant_type' in body

Tags: typescript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, nestjs, office365api

I want to get into Microsoft Azure and Graph and created a simple application that should consume the Graph API as a background worker. *I only have a demo account for now but I think this shouldn't matter*.

I'm following this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token

because I don't need a user account for this. First I want to get an access token using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). I use NestJs so Axios gets wrapped into a [HTTP module](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module).

So what I've done so far is the request setup

```
async getToken(): Promise<any> {
    const requestURL: string = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/2c1714e1-1030-4da9-af5e-59630d7fe05f/oauth2/v2.0/token';

    const requestBody: object = {
        tenant: '2c1714e1-1030-4da9-af5e-59630d7fe05f',
        client_id: 'bec52b71-dc94-4577-9f8d-b8536ed0e73d',
        scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        client_secret: 'OV/NkBIWH7d3G/BGyJQN3vxQA]fT6qK@',
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    };

    const requestConfiguration: object = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
    };

    const observableResult: Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> = this.httpService.post(requestURL, requestBody, requestConfiguration);
    return observableResult.toPromise();
}
```

I get a **400** HTTP error with the following message:

> "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter:
>   'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID:
>   038a3bf5-9396-4a4c-9dd6-b4608f265800\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   a1871bfc-af0d-470e-b604-f94ea4f10325\r\nTimestamp: 2019-12-21
>   23:10:11Z"

Did I misunderstand the docs? What is wrong or missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know JS enough to be sure but could it be that the value of your secret is not url encoded and so the non-url firendly characters in it truncate the request body? Can you url-encode it first and then past into your app?

Comment: hey, sorry, I used `encodeURIComponent(clientSecret)` but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is perfectly correct (postman gets token with your data). But seems that you've made error when making POST request.

As [doc](http://login.microsoftonline.com) mentioned by you says, `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So you first need to convert `requestBody` to URL encoded form (`key=value&key2=value2`), and not add it to url but pass as body. This is not obvious part...

```
const requestURL: string = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/2c1714e1-1030-4da9-af5e-59630d7fe05f/oauth2/v2.0/token';

const requestBody: object = {
    tenant: '2c1714e1-1030-4da9-af5e-59630d7fe05f',
    client_id: 'bec52b71-dc94-4577-9f8d-b8536ed0e73d',
    scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    client_secret: 'OV/NkBIWH7d3G/BGyJQN3vxQA]fT6qK@',
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
};

let request = Object.keys(requestBody).map(k => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(requestBody[k])}`).join('&')
this.httpService.post(requestURL, request, { headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. I tried to use your code example here https://hatebin.com/cnkgpbvsup unfortunately I get the same error :( `"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: 641aaaae-7ac7-4d91-933b-be5a41855900\r\nCorrelation ID: 81f748af-a13c-4f73-b8ba-addd790b3266\r\nTimestamp: 2019-12-22 07:04:12Z"`

Answer (score 0):

Get access token:

```
'use strict';

const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

const accessTokenWithCredentials = (tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, resource) => {
    const data = {
        resource: resource,
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',

    };
    
    return axios({
        url: `https://login.windows.net/${tenantId}/oauth2/token`,
        method: "post",
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        auth: {
        username: clientId,
        password: clientSecret,
        },
        data:  qs.stringify(data)
    }).catch(error => {
        throw error;
    })
};
```

To call the function:

```
accessTokenWithCredentials(<tenantId>, <clientId>, <clientSecret>, 'https://graph.microsoft.com').then(response => {
    console.log(`Got access token`);
    const token = JSON.stringify(response.data.access_token);

    // do what you need to do

}).catch(err => {
     console.log("err " + err);
     throw err;
});
```